# FreeTexBox in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, freetextbox

I've downloaded and using FreeTextBox control in visual studio 2010 (.Net Framework 4.0)
but i got the following error. [image]

Answer (score 0):

You might try to run depends on its dll to see if needs other dlls that can not be found (might be some vcredist dll).